# Not able to split by [] and replace string from array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace name with id.
I have array of object like:

```
let obj = [{
id: 123,
name: 'abcd',
},{
id: 234,
name: 'new name',
}];
```

And I have string.

```
let str = "[123] Hello how are you? [234] and you? [123] Please call me."
```

I am trying to replace id [123] with name.
But, split not working properly and couldn't find good way to replace all.

I tried.

```js
let obj = [{
  id: 123,
  name: 'abcd',
}, {
  id: 234,
  name: 'new name',
}];

let str = "[123] Hello how are you? [234] and you? [123] Please call me."

let transformedMessage = str.split('[')[0];

//Or even following way don't know how to replace particular Id with name.

obj.forEach(val => {
str = str.replace(/\[.*?\]\s?/g, val.name)
});

console.log(str);
```

But, it gives blank data.

I am trying to get string like:
"abcd Hello how are you? new name and you?"

Comment: I would do it with `.replace()` and a regular expression.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that tries to replace anything. `split` creates an array like `["", "123] Hello how are you? ". "234] and you?"]`, I don't see how that's useful for what you want to do.

Comment: What are you really trying to do though? This feels like a hack way of handling things in a world where string interpolation and formatting exists...

Comment: @Pointy I added some code.

Comment: @Barmar Please check I edited my question with more information

Comment: Your first iteration of the loop will replace all `[...]` with the first name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can loop on your array and replace id occurences with name value.

is something like following works for you?

```js
function solve(){
  let obj = [{
    id: 123,
    name: 'abcd',
  }, {
    id: 234,
    name: 'new name',
  }];

  let str = "[123] Hello how are you? [234] and you?";
  
  obj.forEach(o=> {
     str = str.replace('['+o.id+']', o.name);
  });
  
  console.log(str);
 
}

solve();
```

And this is for all occurences

```js
function solve(){
  let obj = [{
    id: 123,
    name: 'abcd',
  }, {
    id: 234,
    name: 'new name',
  }];

  let str = "[123] Hello how are you? [234] and you?";
  
  obj.forEach(o=> {
     str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\[' +o.id+ '\\]', 'gi'), o.name);
  });
  
  console.log(str);
 
}

solve();
```

Comment: One caveat: This will only work if each `[xxx]` only appears once in the string.

Comment: Your regexp doesn't check for `[]` around the ID. It will replace `123` outside brackets. Also, It will replace `[1234]` with the replacement for `123`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the string-replace function of javascript.

```
let obj = [{
   id: 123,
   name: 'abcd',
 }, {
   id: 234,
   name: 'new name',
}];
    
let str = "[123] Hello how are you? [234] and you?"
    
obj.forEach(el => {    
    transformedMessage = str.replace('[' + el.id + ']', el.name);
})
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as the other answer?

Comment: ^^ oops... it took me too long apparently ;-)